# why is dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile) not working anymore

Tags: r, path

I have used

dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile)

to get the directory of the script I am currently running

It worked perfectly until recently where it returns an error message

Error in sys.frame(1) : not that many frames on the stack

I have my code and data in Dropbox, and since I run it on various computers where dropbox is located differently, I want to be able to know where the script running is located.

Any idea why dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile) does not work anymore, and how to get a solution.

There is a lot having the same problem as I, but the solutions either dont work or suggest another way which does not fit.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112128/how-do-i-get-script-directory-in-r